# Java How to remove trailing and leading escape slashes in string

Tags: java, regex

For example, I have a string `a="\\a\\b\\";`

How to remove all escape slashes in leading and trailing for it, so the processed string will be `a\\b`.

I tried using:

```
a=a.replaceFirst("\\+$", "");
a=a.replaceFirst("\\+", "");
```

But it's not working correctly as I expected.

Comment: What can you think of as a reasonable approach? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use two regexes:

```
String a = "\\\\a\\b\\\\\\";
System.out.println(
   a.replaceAll("^\\\\+", "")
    .replaceAll("\\\\+$", "")
);
```

So many bars, right? This is because to express a single `"\"` in a String, we need to scape it with another bar, which will be `"\\"`. But, `\` is also a special char for regular expressions, so you need to scape it too.

That is why you need four `\\\\`, which will be "translated" to just two.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the String from start until you hit a non slash and remove slashes before it and vice versa for trailing.

I wouldn't use a regex for something this trivial.